# How to get newly created sales order internal id in suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitetalk

I'm writing a suitescript to send order details to a customer email address.

Is it possible to get the sales order id through scriptContext or similar method?

My function is run on Sales Order After Submit.

```
function afterSubmit(scriptContext){

     soid = scriptContext.soid; //<--trying to get the sales order id

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an afterSubmit, you can use `scriptContext.newRecord.id`.

See `afterSubmit` documentation here: https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4407992281.html

and `record.Record` object members documentation here:  https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4267255811.html#bridgehead_4273190849